# Lagrange Interpolating Polynomials with custom way to add Local Maximum/Minimum.

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

Given this data table consists of 10 points:

x | -3 1 2 4 5 6 9 11 12 14

y | 2 3 -2 0 -3 1 -1 0 -2 1

Construct a polynomial P(x) such that its graph passes through the points in the data table
and P(x) has a local maximum at M3(2,−2), a local minimum at M5(5,−3), and a saddle
point at M8(11, 0).

For this problem, I first thought about Lagrange Polynomial to construct the function P(x):

**(1807093*x^9/61751289600)−(5058059*x^8/3087564480)+(5106197*x^7/137837700)−(13208401247*x^6/30875644800)+(14385778741*x^5/5613753600)−(191204226071*x^4/30875644800)−(142786904483*x^3/15437822400)+(23555534161*x^2/285885600)−(8112434009*x/53603550)+(1318323/15470)**

Here's the Desmos link for its graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j2b9vofetd

But I can't think of any way to add Local Maximum/Minimum to the function, I tried to Derivative to  get P'(x) then force the P'(x=minimum) = 0 but that would mess up the whole function. I even tried to add a "running" point but that doesn't work either.

Any idea about solving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming you've done the calculations correctly, so your $P(x)$ passes through the ten points, you can add to it $C(x+3)^{r_1}(x-1)^{r_2}\cdots(x-14)^{r_{10}}$ where $C$ is any real, and $r_1,\dots,r_{10}$ are any positive integers, and still get a polynomial through the ten points. Now you just have to choose all those parameters so you get the derivatives to work out.

Comment: Quick and dirty: augment the table by inserting some new points  that make the local behavior near M3 look  like a frown-shaped parabolic $\cap$,  near M5 look like an upward parabolic $\cup$,etc.   Example: Near M3 add  a pair of new points by adding $\epsilon =\pm .2$ to $x$ and $-\epsilon^2=-.04$ to $y$.  In effect you are forcing the curve to pass through points that lie on an arc of the correct shape.

Comment: Care to engage with the comments, An Dinh?

Comment: @MathWonk Yeah, I did try that method by adding a "running point" fake a curve but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @GerryMyerson Let me try your method and I will let you know ASAP if it works! Thanks for the advice btw